# Add value to database with ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to add value 'Nova parcela' to database in table zemljiste so I write first ajax code:

```
<script>
var nova_parcela = 'Nova parcela';
 $("#dodaj").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "insert.php",
            type: "POST",
            async: true, 
            data: { name:nova_parcela}, //your form data to post goes here as a json object
            dataType: "html",

            success: function(data) {
                $('#output').html(data);
                drawVisualization();   
            },  
        });

});
</script>
```

after that I write php code: INSERT.php is:

```
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

 if (!$_POST['name']!='Nova parcela') {
            echo "<p>Popunite sva polja</p>";
            exit;
        } else {
            try {        
                $DBH = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
                $STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO zemljiste (naziv) VALUES (:name)");

                $STH->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name']);

                $STH->execute();

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
            echo "<p>Data submitted successfully</p>".$_POST['ajdi'];

        }

    }

    $DBH = null;
```

but nothing happend , what can be a problem here?

Comment: What are you intending to do here `if (!$_POST['name']!='Nova parcela')`?

Comment: ok, that is no so imortant to me so i can delete ths part of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try change that

```
   if (!$_POST['name']!='Nova parcela') {
```

to

```
  if (!isset($_POST['name'])) {
```

EDIT:

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {

        try {        
            $DBH = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
            $STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO zemljiste (naziv) VALUES (:name)");

            $STH->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name']);

            $STH->execute();
            $datas['msg']= "success" ;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

      $DBH = null;
     echo json_encode($datas);
    }
```

and your script:

```
  <script>
 var nova_parcela = 'Nova parcela';
  $("#dodaj").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "insert.php",
        type: "POST",
        async: true, 
        data: { name:nova_parcela}, //your form data to post goes here as a json object
        dataType: "json",

        success: function(data) {
               if (data.msg == 'success'){
                   $('#output').html("<p>Data submitted successfully</p>"+nova_parcela);
                   drawVisualization();   
                  }
            else{
         $('#output').html("<p>Popunite sva polja</p>");
              }
        }  
    });

 });
 </script>
```

Comment: is anything inserted in the database? when not try an print_r($_POST); in the insert.php
when yes make a alert(data); in the success function and look the page returns

Comment: also I run php code without error hadling but again I just get white screen

Comment: are you making the submit to insert.php ? show your html form.

Comment: no I dont have a form, I have only var nova_parcela, that value I need to add to database

Comment: in html i have only this: <button class="btn btn-success" id="dodaj"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Dodaj novu parcelu</button></div>

Comment: output is not hidden, but when I click on button with ID dodaj, nothing happend

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49578/discussion-between-gmaestro-and-echo-me)